# Apache Phoenix CURRENT_TIME() gives NPE

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am attempting to use Apache Phoenix's filter on timestamp column.

My table and column exists.  The column is of type TIMESTAMP. https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#timestamp_type

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase> SELECT * FROM METRIC where METRIC_ID = 'process.cpu' AND METRIC_TIMESTAMP > NOW();
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ScanRanges.getAscTimeRange(ScanRanges.java:674)
```

I also tried with CURRENT_TIME()

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase> SELECT * FROM METRIC where METRIC_ID = 'process.cpu' AND METRIC_TIMESTAMP > CURRENT_TIME();
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ScanRanges.getAscTimeRange(ScanRanges.java:674)
at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ScanRanges.getRowTimestampColumnRange(ScanRanges.java:658)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug - please file a JIRA. A workaround would be to declare METRIC_TIMESTAMP as a DATE instead of TIMESTAMP. The DATE type in Phoenix has a granularity of millisecond.

Comment: Will do. I have a similar issue for auto-generated timestamps.

Comment: In order to workaround should I use map the type to sql.Date? Will that maintain granularity to millis?

Comment: In your create table statement declare METRIC_TIMESTAMP to be of type DATE: CREATE TABLE METRIC (...., METRIC_TIMESTAMP DATE). Phoenix uses an 8 byte epoch long to store the date, so it's always at a granularity of millis. Make sure to use a SQL client that shows the full granularity - for example, sqlline only shows the day part of a DATE. You can use SELECT TO_CHAR(METRIC_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') FROM METRIC;